# Error when I`m trying to get word-level timestamps in OpenAI's Whisper ASR

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, openai-api, openai-whisper

Im trying to get word-level timestamps in OpenAI's Whisper ASR. Im doing for this:

`transcription_words = model.transcribe(audio=input_wav, language='ru', word_timestamps=True)`
input_wav is str (path to wav file).

It works with word_timestamps=False, but with True I get:

```
----> 2 transcription_words = model.transcribe(audio=input_wav, language='ru', word_timestamps=True)

File c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\whisper\transcribe.py:323, in transcribe(model, audio, verbose, temperature, compression_ratio_threshold, logprob_threshold, no_speech_threshold, condition_on_previous_text, initial_prompt, word_timestamps, prepend_punctuations, append_punctuations, **decode_options)
    320     seek += segment_size
    322 if word_timestamps:
--> 323     add_word_timestamps(
    324         segments=current_segments,
    325         model=model,
    326         tokenizer=tokenizer,
    327         mel=mel_segment,
    328         num_frames=segment_size,
    329         prepend_punctuations=prepend_punctuations,
    330         append_punctuations=append_punctuations,
    331         last_speech_timestamp=last_speech_timestamp,
    332     )
    333     word_end_timestamps = [
    334         w["end"] for s in current_segments for w in s["words"]
    335     ]
    336     if len(word_end_timestamps) > 0:

File c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\whisper\timing.py:298, in add_word_timestamps(segments, model, tokenizer, mel, num_frames, prepend_punctuations, append_punctuations, last_speech_timestamp, **kwargs)
    292 text_tokens_per_segment = [
    293     [token for token in segment["tokens"] if token < tokenizer.eot]
    294     for segment in segments
    295 ]
    297 text_tokens = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(text_tokens_per_segment))
--> 298 alignment = find_alignment(model, tokenizer, text_tokens, mel, num_frames, **kwargs)
    299 word_durations = np.array([t.end - t.start for t in alignment])
    300 word_durations = word_durations[word_durations.nonzero()]

File c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\whisper\timing.py:210, in find_alignment(model, tokenizer, text_tokens, mel, num_frames, medfilt_width, qk_scale)
    208 std, mean = torch.std_mean(weights, dim=-2, keepdim=True, unbiased=False)
    209 weights = (weights - mean) / std
--> 210 weights = median_filter(weights, medfilt_width)
    212 matrix = weights.mean(axis=0)
    213 matrix = matrix[len(tokenizer.sot_sequence) : -1]

File c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\whisper\timing.py:35, in median_filter(x, filter_width)
     30 assert (
     31     filter_width > 0 and filter_width % 2 == 1
     32 ), "`filter_width` should be an odd number"
     34 result = None
---> 35 x = F.pad(x, (filter_width // 2, filter_width // 2, 0, 0), mode="reflect")
     36 if x.is_cuda:
     37     try:

File c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:4157, in _pad(input, pad, mode, value)
   4155 assert value == 0, 'Padding mode "{}"" doesn\'t take in value argument'.format(mode)
   4156 if input.dim() == 3:
-> 4157     assert len(pad) == 2, "3D tensors expect 2 values for padding"
   4158     if mode == "reflect":
   4159         return torch._C._nn.reflection_pad1d(input, pad)

AssertionError: 3D tensors expect 2 values for padding
```

Im trying to get transcription with timestamps for every word in audio.
I also tried to put tensor instead of str, but there was another Error:
`"reflection_pad1d" not implemented for 'Short'`

How can I solve this problem?